# How to set the start point of bar chart

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bar-chart, sfml

I am creating the bar chart by using SFML library and Visual-C++. I want to set the starting point of the bar chart, so I try to use move and setOrigin function but it cannot be a success.

```
sf::RectangleShape rec1(sf::Vector2f(stage1x*1000, stage1y*1000));
sf::RectangleShape rec2(sf::Vector2f(stage2x*1000, stage2y*1000));
sf::RectangleShape rec3(sf::Vector2f(stage3x*1000, stage3y*1000));

rec1.setOrigin(0, 0);
rec2.setOrigin(0, 0);
rec3.setOrigin(0, 0);

rec1.move(200, 700); // This moves the Rectangle over 200 pixels and down 700 pixels
rec2.move(300, 700); // This moves the Rectangle over 300 pixels and down 700 pixels
rec3.move(400, 700); // This moves the Rectangle over 400 pixels and down 700 pixels

rec1.setFillColor(sf::Color(100, 250, 50));
rec2.setFillColor(sf::Color(10, 20, 100));
rec3.setFillColor(sf::Color(500, 600, 700));
```

[image: This is a picture of my bar chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of different approaches for this. For example, you could set the height of your window's `sf::View` to a negative value, which would essentially flip everything vertically (coordinates running from bottom to top).

`setOrigin()` on SFML's drawables will only move their local origin, i.e. determine which point is aligned to the position given in `setPosition()̀`. By default, the origin is set to `(0, 0)`, so your code doesn't change anything.

Rather than using `move()`, I'd call `setPosition()` directly (which is setting an absolute position rather than a relative one). If you want the bars to go upwards, either flip the view as described above or simply subtract the bars' height from their Y position.